# What are the underlying assumptions behind relevance score and cost function in pairwise learning to rank?

Tags: machine-learning, ranking, information-retrieval

So I have three questions about pairwise learning to rank.

1- Is it assumed that the relevance score associated with the items to be rank is a discrete value?

2- For a discrete value, does a rule of thumb exist that how many training samples do you need for k grades of relevance? For example, if my items have an associated relevance score ranging from 1-10 how many samples do I need to train a model?

3- Is there an existing algorithm that the lost functions penalized for all the items in the ranking similarly? (not penalize for the mismatch in the top ones more than the others)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can answer the first question. One thing that I learned is that it is really important how the ranking algorithm uses the relevance scores to train a model. If the underlying model is trying to do a  regression task then continuous values should be fine. However, if the underlying model is doing an ordered classification task then the values should be grades and therefore discrete. You can always try to discretize your continuous values however, discretizing the relevance scores is a good decision or not depends on the problem at hand.